# Prove $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} (A\cap U_i) =A\cap \left(\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} U_i\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that
$$\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} (A\cap U_i) =A\cap \left(\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} U_i\right)?$$

I guess it follows from the properties $A\cap A=A$ and $A\cap B=B\cap A$ as for the finite case, but if $I$ is infinite does it still hold?

Comment: Sure: both consist exactly of the elements which belong to $A$ as well as all the $U_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is exactly the same for a finite intersection or an infinite one. If $x$ belongs to the LHS it belongs to $A\cap U_i$ for all $i \in I$ and therefore to $A$ and all U$_i$. Hence $x$ belongs to the RHS. And conversely.

In the proof, no hypothesis on the fact that $I$ is finite is required.